# How to implement the half page scroll functionality

Tags: facebook

On Mouse scroll event in Facebook, How some portion of page is not scrolling, while other part going down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in the CSS file, just by adding `position:fixed;` to the class you want to fix. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp